# Why should we only use snapshot on GLSurfaceView in the "onDrawFrame" method? Otherwise, it will end up with a black empty image

Tags: android, bitmap, snapshot, glsurfaceview

Currently I'm trying to get the snapshot from GLSurfaceView on Android. My method here is to generate a bitmap which shows the real-time content of GLSurfaceView. The actual algorithm I use is:

```
Bitmap createBitmapFromView(int x, int y, int width, int height, GL10 gl) throws OutOfMemoryError{
    int buffer[] = new int[width * height];
    int source[] = new int[width * height];

    IntBuffer intBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    intBuffer.position(0);

    try{
        gl.glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, intBuffer);

        int offset1, offset2;
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            offset1 = i * width;
            offset2 = (height - i - 1) * width;

            for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
                int texturePixel = buffer[offset1 + j];

                int blue = (texturePixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int red = (texturePixel << 16) & 0x00ff0000;
                int pixel = (texturePixel & 0xff00ff00) | red | blue;

                source[offset2 + j] = pixel;
            }
        }
    } catch(GLException e){
        return null;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

However, as for the usage of this method, my original idea is to make the class that extended from GLSurfaceView to create a new GL10 instance for displaying. Just after the surface had been created, I call this function above in method "onSurfaceCreated". Then, I found out every snapshot for now is totally empty in black, which looks like that the image data never pass through this GLSurfaceView.

After several other tests with different places to use the algorithm, I accidentally found out only you call this function inside of the method "onDrawFrame". So I just set up a boolean flag in the renderer of the GLSurfaceView to mark if currently we need a snapshot. Since GLSurfaceView will keep calling "onDrawFrame" function to refresh, whenever the flag is true, I do the snapshot and set the flag to false. It finally works.

Thus, my question here is: why should we only call the method to make it work in the "onDrawFrame" instead of any place which can get the instance of GL10? Anyone know what is the difference among the different place to call the snapshot method?

Comment: This behavior is due to how GPU and CPU works. GPU has its own dedicated memory this is  where framebuffer is stored. To be able to maximize performance, by default, CPU cannot read GPU dedicated memory. Reading framebuffer from CPU will make GPU to stop its operation  thus very expensive.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful.